# how do i call a webservice using phonegap for android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl, cordova

How do I make a webservice call from my phonegap app? I found two javascript libraries one from IBM and another IvanWebService http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/43725416/SOAP%20Web%20Service that allow you to make such calls but i couldnt get them to run any of my webservices. I am passing in a wsdl link as the service link and i have updated the envelope parameters, still nothing.

Comment: see this link http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/02/callling-web-services-in.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it were me, I would use jQuery.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1853-Posting-XML-SOAP-Requests-With-jQuery.htm
http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/
http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx

Comment: what if i was going with sencha instead of jquery or none of those two libraries, is there a way to make the call just from a simple javascript on phonegap?

Comment: Some quick Googling makes it seem like Sencha does not have any specific support for SOAP. So you would probably be able to make the Ajax call to the service but you would have to construct and deconstruct the SOAP envelopes manually.

Comment: Yes you could probably do it without any JavaScript library, but it would not be "simple" Javascript. It would be a mass of ugly network calls, regular expressions for parsing XML, and string concatenations for creating SOAP envelops. IT would likely not be pretty, and unless you are really good at regex it would probably be error prone too. That's the beauty of jQuery. It makes JavaScript cleaner and more elegant.  Even if you did not use jQuery, you would likely end up looking for other libraries that would do the same things.

Comment: Thanks all, i will be looking at jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#requestXML").click(function() {

                     $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://YOURSITE/script.php",
                      data: "{}",
                      cache: false,
                      dataType: "xml",
                      success: onSuccess
                    });

            });

            $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
              $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
            });

             function onSuccess(data)
              {   alert(data);
               }


        });

        </script>

</head>
```

Button to call the above method:

```
<input id="requestXML" type="button" value="Request XML" />
```